# Set custom values from element data-attribute in slider jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set the values of the slider when it is created, how can I do it?
Example:

```
<div class="slider" data-min-value="0"  data-max-value="120"><input type="range"></div>





$('.slider').slider({
            range: true,
            create: function(event, ui) {
                console.log($(this).data('minValue'));
                ui.values[0] = $(this).data('minValue');
                ui.values[1] = $(this).data('maxValue');
            },
})
```

But `ui` is empty.

Comment: Why would you have a `range` input inside a jQuery UI slider ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ui.values` array is just an argument, changing it doesn't change the settings of the slider.

You change the settings like this

```
$('.slider').slider({
    range: true,
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).slider( "option", "max", $(this).data('maxValue') );
        $(this).slider( "option", "min", $(this).data('minValue') );
    }
});
```

Note that you'd usually just do this on instantiation

```
$('.slider').each(function() {
    $(this).slider({
        max: $(this).data('maxValue'),
        min: $(this).data('minValue')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For data attributes accessed using the `.data()` method, do not use camelCase:

```
ui.values[0] = $(this).data('min-value');
ui.values[1] = $(this).data('max-value');
```

Only use camelCase [when you're using the native `.dataset` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes#JavaScript_Access), i.e.:

```
ui.values[0] = $(this)[0].dataset.minValue;
ui.values[1] = $(this)[0].dataset.maxValue;
```